# How to get text value of selected text from onSelect DOM event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Think this is a simple question, but I am very new to web dev so I apologize :) -> on an onSelect event, how do I grab the content of what was selected? And is there a way to modify the text that was selected, such as highlighting?

This is what I have so far:

```
<textarea id="text">
Text to be highlighted
</textarea>
```

in js:

```
let text_selection   = document.getElementById("text");
text_selection.addEventListener("select", highlightText);

function highlightText(){
  alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to grab the selected text you can use `textarea.selectionStart` and `textarea.selectionEnd` as mentioned in another answer

To solve second part of the question you will need some CSS rule to highlight the selected text. please check the code snippet.

```js
let text_selection = document.getElementById("text");
text_selection.addEventListener("select", highlightText);

function highlightText() {
  let textarea = event.target;
  let selection = textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd);
  console.log(selection)
}
```

```css
::-moz-selection {
  color: yellow;
}

::selection {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">
Text to be highlighted
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the starting and ending offset of the selection from the event target, and use substring to figure out the selection

```
text_selection.addEventListener("select", highlightText);

function highlightText(event){
    let textarea = event.target;
    let selection = textarea.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd);
    alert(selection)
    // ^^ don't use alert
    console.log(selection); 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event